# jquery - why does $.ajax call the success handler when the request is aborted because my server is down?

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I bring my server down and make an ajax request to it, firebug shows that the request is aborted a few seconds after making the request, and my `success` handler gets called.

Why does the success handler get called, shouldn't it be the error handler?  And how can I reliably detect that it wasn't actually a success?

CODE:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data, statusText, xhr){
                  //gets called on success, or even when server is down.
                },
                error: function(){
                  //called if server returns error, but not if it doesn't respond
                }
            });
```

UPDATE: This behavior is only on localhost, it happens when turning off my development server.
I tested to see what happens when I try to reach the production server, but have my personal internet taken offline, and it just hangs, not calling success or error at all.  Guess I should set the timeout property for that case.

Comment: Not positive, but maybe the response of `abort` is different than `fail`? can you post your code?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357147/ajax-how-to-prevent-jquery-from-calling-the-success-event-after-executing-xmlhtt

Comment: How do you take the server down? Is it completely unreachable, or will it serve 404 pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug (?) in the 1.4.2 version of jQuery.

I quote one comment from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> In 1.4.2 jquery doesn't call ajax
>   error callback on timeout/connection
>   error, to fix this: remove the
>   trailing " || xhr.status === 0" from
>   httpSuccess function

Make that if  you do want to modify the jQuery code itself. Else you can check it in your success callback like I make here:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://madeUpServerthatdoesnotExist.com/index.php",
   data: "id=1",
   success: function(msg){
     if(this.xhr().status === 0 ){
           errorHandler();
     }
     else {
           alert('Success');
     }
   },
    error: errorHandler
 });

function errorHandler(){
            alert('Freakin error');
}
```

It seems to be tricky, please comment if you know about a better way!

**EDIT:** After researching, I'm not sure that this could be a bug in jQuery, will update the answer as soon as I get a clue

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this bug was fixed in jQuery 1.4.3:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6060