# cancel ajax() success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using dynamic pagination.

I need to cancel the `success` event in jQuery `ajax` before starting another.

I've set a variable equal to `$.ajax()`, and before doing so, I call `abort` no matter what.

The problem is that `success` still fires.

The answer for [Ajax: How to prevent jQuery from calling the success event after executing xmlHttpRequest.abort();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357147/ajax-how-to-prevent-jquery-from-calling-the-success-event-after-executing-xmlht) is wrong, or at least it doesn't work for me because if I fire `abort` right after the `ajax` nothing ever happens.

I just want the `success` of the `ajax` variable not to fire if another one is about to start.

**Code Snippet:**

```
if(updatePageAJAX){
    updatePageAJAX.abort();
}

updatePageAJAX = $.ajax({
});
```

I can provide more detail if you like, but `updatePageAJAX` works.  I couldn't tell you if `abort` works.  I put an `alert` in the `if` to see if it fires; it does.

If I put `abort` right after setting `updatePageAJAX = $.ajax`, nothing ever happens.

Comment: The answer to that question worked for me in many occasions...Can  you post some code? Maybe problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried saving your xhr object in a variable so that you can check in the success callback if it is the right xhr object?
For example:

```
$(function() {
    var xhr = null;

    $('.link').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).text();
        if(xhr != null) {
            xhr.abort();
        }
        xhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'index.php',
            data: 'js=true&page=' + page,
            success: function(data, responseCode, jqxhr) {
                if(xhr == jqxhr) {
                    $('#page').text(data);
                    xhr = null;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This way, the success callback won't execute if this is not the right request.

Comment: Thank you for trying!  Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  Won't `xhr` be equal to `jqxhr` right before the `success` function is called?

Comment: Yes, it will be equal, but when "another one is about to start" you could put the hxr variable to null so that the condition xhr == jqxhr will be false. In this example, the xhr variable is set by the AJAX call so that if two AJAX calls are made almost simultaneously, only the later will be in the xhr variable so the first success callback wont execute because there is a false condition. Cannot you do something like that in your code? If no, why?

Comment: I tried your code, and it doesn't work.  Is there anything in the `jqXHR` that is distinguishable for each ajax call?  Can I manually set it?

Comment: This worked for me. Even if there were a problem with all xhr's appearing to be equal, you could do something like "xhr.stamp = new Date().getTime()" immediately after the ajax() call, then compare the stamp values in the success callback.